# How to achieve on first click listener in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have a **customView** , i want to set onClick which will only be called on the very first click. In which i want to start a thread which will start a **counter** on other **TextView** , with simple **onClickListener** with each click a new threads starts which is a problem . How can i achieve such task ?

Comment: why negative vote did i asked anything wrong? or duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is in your `onClick()` method do set a null listener, i.e.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // disable any other clicks from now on
    customView.setOnClickListener(null);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only logic problem, So I solve this problem by using a boolean variable for the first click:

```
    boolean isFristClick = true;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isFristClick) {
            // Start your counter Thread here
            isFristClick = false;
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }

    }
```

Comment: at first i was thinking the same but , it will always called onClick to check whether it is okay to run chunk of code or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a workaround for that?!! like assigning a boolean value to tell if it's the first click:

```
private boolean first_click = true;

your_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(first_click){
             first_click = false;
             // Do something on first click
        }else{
             // Do another thing on later clicks
        }

    }
});
```